# Merge Twitter Outh and Facebook Connect Friends

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-networking

Basically what I want to do is download all a users facebook and twitter friends and somehow find a way to figure out which entries represent the same person.  I know it's possible because a lot of social search sites like spokeo achieve what I want and more, so does anyone know how they go about doing it or the best way to go about it?

I have a basic idea of the facebook and twitter api calls I need to be making however feel free to add any advice or warnings there as well.  I know facebook hashes the emails which seems like it could pose a problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would allow the users to make associations themselves. Then use these associations as suggestions for future users. Over time you'll gather quite a well made associations from your users. Possibly using email addresses and names as suggestion points.

Comment: Hmm that's one possibility and perhaps that's how they do it although I'd think there's got to be a more automated way to do it.

Thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: well, there isn't a way to be 100% certain user names are going to be the same on all systems. so we cant really be certain that @jayrox on twitter is jayrox on facebook. or that email addresses are used in both systems. I'm fairly certain you will need some user interaction to get it started. over time you will be able to start using automated suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

tried using [hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/), you will get the emails from facebook and twitter which you can use to build the relationships needed